# convert all  NSDate objects into array to NSString objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an xml file having list of .Every date has a list of events.i want to display the date in uisegmentation control.when the user click the date in uisegmentation i am displaying the list of event for the date shown below.My xml structure is

`<event>

</title>

</desc>

   <date>01/02/2012</date>

</event>`

I done everything the problem is.I am getting all dates and remove duplicates

```
[ datearray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.date"]
```

and i sort the date using

```
sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)
```

***Now  my array has a list of nsdate object .I want to convert nsdate object to nsstring..***

I tried **for** loop and **nsdateformatter**  to check every index and change into string and add into new array..it's a lengthy process...is it correct or any other better option

Finally

```
 UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:datearray]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question right, you want to convert all the NSDate objects in your mutable array to NSString objects.

```
NSArray *arrayOfStrings=[dateArray valueForKey:@"description"];
```

`valueForKey:` will be called on all objects of date array and the results will be stored in the new array.